Demultiplex double hashed cells using Seurat (R)
I am using Seurat to demultiplex my single-cell RNA data, which also has HTO data for hashing. Each cell is hashed once based off it's origin ie organ1, and then hashed based off the cell type ie cell type1.
The resulting hashing should appear as Organ1CellType1, Organ1CellType2, Organ2CellType1 and so on.
Can anyone advise on the best way to tackle this to be able to demultiplex using Seurat? I would like to end up with an object that has information on the organ and cell type based off this hashing.
I am attempting to do this now by splitting up the hashes into the Organ and CellType and demultiplexing them separately, but it is proving a mess when I try to use the HTO data for Rideplot etc when I try to remerge the metadata with the hash labelled cells.
